# Set Visibility of Panel Inside Update Panel From Code behind From An Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have simplified and probably made a typo or two below, but I am trying to show and hide the visibility of pnl2, this code however doesn't work.  I thought as long as the panel was in another update panel I can control visibility.

Oddly enough if I debug this in Visual studio, and F10 all the way through it, it shows the visibility correctly, but when I hit my Last F10 and the page loads, it's always incorrect.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ID="updPanel1">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="pnl1"/>
<asp:Button runat="Server" ID="hidePanel2" OnClick="HidePanel2"/>
</ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>


<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ID="updPanel2">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="pnl2"/>
</ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>

protected void hidePanel2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (pnl2.Visible == true)
{
    pnl2.Visible = false;
}else
{
    pnl2.Visible = true;)
}
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure pnl2.Visible is not being set anywhere else in the code.

Comment: 2. Why don't you have anything inside <asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="pnl2"/> ??

Comment: Yes, as I said I stepped through and added a watch to it, I literally stepped through to the end and it never changed.

Comment: Just demo code, sanitized it for ease of reading

Comment: When you say it never changed you mean the Visibility value of pnl2 even after it was set to true?

Comment: Yes, if the visibility has landed on true, in my watch for pnl2.Visible it will hit the code above and show as pnl2.Visible = true, however the page will still not render it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58032/discussion-between-sev-and-jstellato).

Comment: Why is there no triggers defined in update panel? Afaik, you need to provide that in order to make update panel work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to update the visibility of “pnl2” from a button that is in the UpdatePanel named “updPanel1”.  The postback for the button “hidePanel2” only causes the content of update panel “updPanel1” to change.  The rest of the form, including update panel “updPanel2”, does not change.

The most direct solution, if the two panels are next to each other, is to put them both in one update panel.  If you have some other layout then you will need to explain what it is before we can help.